# Is Ash's time in Kanto's Safari Zone ever detailed?

Tags: pokemon

When Ash returns to Pallet Town in the first series, I think after he got all the badges and was preparing for the Pokemon League Championships. When they were in Professor Oak's lab, Oak showed off Ash's extra pokemon that was sent to him pointing out that most were Tauros caught in the Safari Zone.

When I first saw the series I didn't recall it ever showing that Ash went there. So I am wondering if Ash's time in Kanto's Safari Zone was ever detailed anywhere, like why he caught nothing but Tauros or what happened in regards to Pikachu (as in the games you aren't allowed to take pokemon into the Safari Zone and I think it was the same in Yellow where you no longer have Pikachu follow you in there until you leave).

Comment: If i am not wrong then he even used one Tauros in a fight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it was shown in episode 35 of the original TV series. All he caught were Tauros', that's because whenever he tried to catch other Pokemon, a group of Tauros would just happen to run pass. That's why Ash only caught Tauros'. As of regards to Pikachu, it was held by Misty who wasn't participating. Kaiser ( in-charge of Safari ) also stated that the only rules were that they could only use Safari Balls and the Fishing Rod he gave them, and that they had to come back when they had ran out of 'Balls'. Break any of those rules, and his "Thunderbolt" would burn them ( this refers to the gun that he was holding ). There was no time limit and you could take your Pokemon in, but you can't use them to battle. Same with FireRed and LeafGreen, the Pokemon stays with you, but you can't use them in battle.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that this episode was banned in a lot of places because of the gun.

Comment: @riley was it banned in the US?

Comment: @KazRodgers Yes, you can see a full list here: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Banned_episodes#Banned_episodes_in_the_English_dub

Comment: @Riley now that would explain why I didn't see it. when this answer said it was an episode I thought free-to-air tv in Australia screwed up......again, but it appears that it (proably) didn't and the episode was just banned

Comment: @Memor-X would you like me to give you a copy of the episode, i LEGALLY downloaded it.

Comment: Wow, strange, that episode was not banned in India. Anyway I don't remember "whenever he tried to catch other Pokemon, a group of Tauros would just happen to run pass" part of the episode .

Comment: @AnkitSharma after he caught a Tauros, he went to catch a rhyhorn but the group of Tauros ran pass so he caught another Tauros